# How to get amCalendar filter in 24hours format (Angular-Moment.js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

I am using angular-moment, and the moment add function: `moment().add(7, 'h');`.

In order to display when an approval will be done.

I have a table showing estimation for approval for various products. I am using `amCalender` filter. The results may for example show today at 10pm etc. I want the time to be in 24 hours format instead (today at 22:00).

Comment: add plunker to see your code

Comment: @CarlosArauz please check out https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266909/should-a-question-that-is-meaningless-without-viewing-an-external-link-be-closed (or similar posts) before asking to add link to code showing the problem. It  is requirement that SO question stands on its own without need to access any other sites - guidance on code can be found [MCVE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [docs](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment#amcalendar-filter) says, [`amCalendar`](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment#amcalendar-filter):

> Format dates using moment.js `calendar()` method.

You can customize moment `calendar` output using [`moment.updateLocale`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/calendar/). By default moment use `'[Today at] LT'`, `'[Tomorrow at] LT'` etc, while in your case you need `'[Today at] HH:mm'` etc.

Here a live working example:

```js
angular.module('MyApp',['angularMoment'])
.run(function(){
  moment.updateLocale('en', {
    calendar : {
      lastDay : '[Yesterday at] HH:mm',
      sameDay : '[Today at] HH:mm',
      nextDay : '[Tomorrow at] HH:mm',
      lastWeek : '[last] dddd [at] HH:mm',
      nextWeek : 'dddd [at] HH:mm',
      sameElse : 'L'
    }
  });
})
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = {};
  $scope.message.time = moment().add(7, 'h');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-moment/1.0.1/angular-moment.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <span>{{message.time | amCalendar}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I did search trough the doc,
But I didnt think about changing LT. 

Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
moment().add(7, 'h').format('H:mm');
```