# Global Variables in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

I've got some date ISO strings that I want to format into human-readable dates. I'm using the [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) library to format these dates inside my template using a filter.

```
<span>{{ $ctrl.date | amCalendar:referenceTime:formats }}</span>
```

I want to customise the format of the date displayed to the following:

```
const dateFormats = {
  relative: {
    sameDay: '[Today at] LT',
    lastWeek: 'DD MMM, YYYY [at] LT',
    sameElse: 'DD MMM, YYYY [at] LT'
  }
}
```

So I can do this in my template:

```
<span>{{ $ctrl.date | amCalendar:null:dateFormats }}</span>
```

However, I want those `dateFormats` to live somewhere globally instead of exclusively inside this component's controller, as I'd like to be able to reference these `dateFormats` in other templates down the line.

Would this qualify as proper use-case to attach `dateFormats` to `$scope` or is there a better way to handle this?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use constant(which is a singleton) to do this.refer this link [link](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2014/11/constants-values-global-variables-in-angularjs-the-right-way/ )]

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42876416/4131048), there is no need to create a custom filter, you can customize `amCalendar` in your `run` function as described in the [docs](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment#usage)

Comment: Should have looked through the docs. This is even better. If you add this as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a custom filter of your own. Something like this:

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .filter('myDateFormat', ['$filter',function ($filter) {
      const dateFormats = {
        relative: {
          sameDay: '[Today at] LT',
          lastWeek: 'DD MMM, YYYY [at] LT',
          sameElse: 'DD MMM, YYYY [at] LT'
        } 
      }
      return function() {
        return $filter('amCalendar')(null, dateFormats)
      }
  }]);
```

Now, you can easily utilize this filter from any template in your module:

```
<span>{{ $ctrl.date | myDateFormat }}</span>
```

Comment: Yeah I think this approach is the best way to go and it keeps me away from globals - for now, haha. Thanks!

Comment: @realph sure, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

What I do for dates is creating a custom filter 
as for example :

```
function ascDateFilter($filter) {
    return function (input) {
        return $filter('date')(input, "dd/MM HH:mm:ss");
    };
}
```

your could do something like this and use the amCalendar filter in your custom filter. With this, you have all the code templating the date in the same filter.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create a custom filter, you can customize [`amCalendar`](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment#amcalendar-filter) in your run function as described in the [`docs`](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment#usage).

Here a working sample:

```js
angular.module('MyApp',['angularMoment'])
.run(function(){
  const dateFormats = {
    calendar: {
      sameDay: '[Today at] LT',
      lastWeek: 'DD MMM, YYYY [at] LT',
      sameElse: 'DD MMM, YYYY [at] LT'
    }
  }
  moment.updateLocale('en', dateFormats);
})
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.date = new Date();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-moment/1.0.1/angular-moment.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <span>{{ date | amCalendar }}</span>
</div>
```